# Changing defaults with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a custom `UITextField` which holds the defaults for a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`. I call it `TextFieldinTableViewCell`. in the `init` functions i call a setUp function which sets things like textColor and autocapitalizationType.
Now it should be by default `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords`, but in a very few cases I want some other type. Now in my storyboard I have this textfield quite often because my app uses static tableviewcells a lot. Because I, obviously, don't want to set these thing each time in **IB** I have the subclass. But now, if I want something other than the subclasses default, of course, the Interface Builder Setting gets overriden.

Thanks in advance